# ImageBackground don't show local image in react native + expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I want to set an background image to my app. When I run `expo start` the image dosen't show.
this its my component:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground } from "react-native";
import { Asset } from "expo-asset";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={{
          uri: Asset.fromModule(require("./images/background.png")).uri,
        }}
        style={styles.image}
      ></ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "cover",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

what I missed? I appreciate any help

Comment: Try using width and height in style image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the react native documentation:

"Note that you must specify some width and height style attributes."

https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground

Comment: Just update your code for styles.image and add width & height property in addition to other style properties